# forward hashmap using post request

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, hashmap

I have a jsp page where I am getting a data-set and this data also contains hashmap. 
So my question how can i forward that data to my other servlet using post request?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the auto form submission technique with having the hashmap as the hidden parameter.